# Search in nested object

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I'm having trouble making a query on elasticsearch 7.3

I create an index as this:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "files": {
        "type": "nested" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After I create three documents:

```
PUT myindex/_doc/1
{
  "SHA256" : "94ee059335e587e501cc4bf90613e0814f00a7b08bc7c648fd865a2af6a22cc2",
  "files" : [
    {
      "filename" : "firstfilename.exe",
      "datetime" :  111111111
    },
    {
      "filename" : "secondfilename.exe",
      "datetime" :  111111144
    }
  ]
}


PUT myindex/_doc/2
{
  "SHA256" : "87ee059335e587e501cc4bf90613e0814f00a7b08bc7c648fd865a2af6a22c5a",
  "files" : [
    {
      "filename" : "thirdfilename.exe",
      "datetime" :  111111133
    },
    {
      "filename" : "fourthfilename.exe",
      "datetime" :  111111122
    }
  ]
}



PUT myindex/_doc/3
{
  "SHA256" : "565e049335e587e501cc4bf90613e0814f00a7b08bc7c648fd865a2af6a22c5a",
  "files" : [
    {
      "filename" : "fifthfilename.exe",
      "datetime" :  111111155
    }   
  ]
}
```

How can I get the last two files based on the datetime (ids: 1 and 3)? 
I would SHA256 of the last two DATETIME ordered by DESC..

I did dozens of tests but none went well...
I don't write the code I tried because I'm really on the high seas ...
I would a result like this or similar:

```
{
 "SHA256": [
             "94ee05933....a2af6a22cc2",
             "565e04933....a2af6a22c5a"
           ]
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific on how the resulting search query would look like. On which field do you want to search? What do you mean with *files*? The documents or the array?

Comment: i want search into array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "_source":"SHA256",
  "sort": [
    {
      "files.datetime": {
        "mode":"max", 
        "order": "desc",
        "nested_path": "files"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 2
}
```

Result:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "SHA256" : "565e049335e587e501cc4bf90613e0814f00a7b08bc7c648fd865a2af6a22c5a"
        },
        "sort" : [
          111111155
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "SHA256" : "94ee059335e587e501cc4bf90613e0814f00a7b08bc7c648fd865a2af6a22cc2"
        },
        "sort" : [
          111111144
        ]
      }
    ]
```

In sort you will get the max date time value . So If you need to get file names too , you can add it in _source and use sort file to get appropriate file name.

A bit more complicated query this will give you exactly two values.

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "_source": "SHA256",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "files",
            "query": {
              "match_all": {}
            },
            "inner_hits": {
              "size":1,
              "sort": [
                {
                  "files.datetime": "desc"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "files.datetime": {
        "mode": "max",
        "order": "desc",
        "nested_path": "files"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 2
}
```

Result:

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "SHA256" : "565e049335e587e501cc4bf90613e0814f00a7b08bc7c648fd865a2af6a22c5a"
        },
        "sort" : [
          111111155
        ],
        "inner_hits" : {
          "files" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "myindex",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "3",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "files",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "filename" : "fifthfilename.exe",
                    "datetime" : 111111155
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    111111155
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "SHA256" : "94ee059335e587e501cc4bf90613e0814f00a7b08bc7c648fd865a2af6a22cc2"
        },
        "sort" : [
          111111144
        ],
        "inner_hits" : {
          "files" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "myindex",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "1",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "files",
                    "offset" : 1
                  },
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "filename" : "secondfilename.exe",
                    "datetime" : 111111144
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    111111144
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```